# App is rendering larger than viewport when I try to apply dynamic css sizing attributes

Tags: javascript, css, window, viewport, sizing

I have tried applying 100vh to the divs root/body/application (these are my top 3 level divs) and my app continues to render larger than the viewport or browser window. I am using display: flex on the child divs.

I am trying to just get the app to fit the window.

Comment: Could you post the code or an example fiddle? That will help with solving the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your element that you set to `100vh`

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This should make sure that any borders, padding or margins won't make the element bigger than the 100vh you've set it to.